# Как получить глобальную geometry от child элемента?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++17

У меня есть label внутри кастомного Frame. 
Пытаюсь сделать перемещение всего приложения по MouseEvent:

```
void settingslogolabel::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    if ((ev->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) && firstCIsNotNull){
             window()->move( mapToGlobal(ev->pos() - m_dragPosition - this->geometry().topLeft()));
    }
}
```

НО! `this->geometry()` возвращает только локальную геометрию.
Собственно вопрос - Как получить глобальную geometry()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Виджет расположен в координатах родителя. Окно расположено в глобальных координатах. Т.е. нужно переводить координаты родителя в глобальные:

```
this->parentWidget()->mapToGlobal(this->pos())
```

С другой стороны, начало координат виджета - его левый верхний угол, т.е. его позиция.
Тогда можно упростить:

```
this->mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0))
```

`QMouseEvent::pos()` возвращает позицию в координатах виджета - получателя. Если вы хотите переместить окно на разницу между ev->pos() и m_dragPosition, смещать нужно именно окно, т.е. нужно менять его позицию в глобальных координатах. Тогда логика следующая:

```
auto prev =  this->mapToGlobal(m_dragPosition)
auto cur =  this->mapToGlobal(ev->pos())
this->window()->move(this->window()->pos() + (cur - prev));
```

Учитывая, что для нормальных виджетов масштабирование недоступно, вызывать mapToGlobal не обязательно, достаточно смещать на разницу между ev->pos() и m_dragPosition.

Comment: Огроменное спасибо